# Multiple items using Multi lookup using visual studio

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, visual-studio

I'm creating a list which has two multi lookup columns to a document library in our project. These columns are Title and Created date. I want to update the Created date column in my list with the date from document library, if one document is selected in my list. How can this be done ?

I have seen that, we can do it through UI, by adding additional columns using a primary lookup column.

But, How can we achieve this while creating a list using Visual Studio ?